# How to write textbox value in string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to get textbox value in a JSON format, but it is giving an error when I am putting "+txtName.Text+" what is the correct format to write textbox value in string

```
 string json = @"
        {


            'MemberName':"+txtName.Text+", 
            'MemeberEmail':'mack @mack.com',
            'MemberPassword':'111'


        }";
```

Code is above

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: 'MemberName': ' abc', --------if i am writting member name like this it is accepting but not in double quotes

Comment: You might want to add single quotes before/after the double quotes around the Textbox-string.

Comment: it is written in c# i need textbox value

Comment: Also I need to know what the Exception is saying. I know that it's written in C# this does not help.

Comment: ) expected this error come when we input wrong format in string

Comment: This error can't be from this code. There's no () and there is also no place where () would make sense. Have you checked the line number and is the error really caused there?

Comment: @Joelius In fact, it *can* be from this code. Why? Because after `txtName.Text` the OP did not create a literal string (missing `@`), so everything after that won't compile correctly

Comment: Got answer  'MemberName':'" + txtName.Text + @"',  is the right format

Comment: @Jitender You might want to look at JSON.NET. Nobody writes JSON like that in c#

Comment: Ahh I see. I couldn't test it myself. But then why ") expected"? I mean why would the compiler expect a ) there? Does it have something to do with mutliline string literals?

Comment: yes run time compiler doesnt permit that

Answer (score 1):

string json = @"
            {

```
            'MemberName':'" + txtName.Text + @"', 
            'MemeberEmail':'" + txtEmail.Text + @"',
            'MemberPassword':'" + txtPassword.Text + @"'


       }";
```

Comment: That is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just do the below thing it will help you out from cause.

```
var mytext = "mytextbox";
            var json =
                new
                {
                    MemberName = mytext,
                    MemeberEmail = "mack @mack.com",
                    MemberPassword = "111"
                };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

for **JsonConvert** use the **Newtonsoft** nuget packege.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Verbatim Literal (`@`) you need to use `""` as an escape sequence within the string. A simple `"` will end the string. Think of it like the `\"` in your ordinary string.

```
string json = @"
    {


        'MemberName':""+txtName.Text+"", 
        'MemeberEmail':'mack @mack.com',
        'MemberPassword':'111'


    }";
```